# Is there a filesystem plugin available for django?

Tags: django, filesystem-browser

For an application I'm writing I would need something like a filesystem browser. I want to expose that through django, and before considering writing one from scratch, I decided to first ask around for something already available. Is there something stable and good which allows for viewing/manipulating files on the server?

Comment: Whose filesystem do you want to browse? And what do you want to do with it?

Comment: The server's filesystem. I want to setup something like a continous integration server, but user-driven. Probably this doesn't make much sense :)

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look [django-filebrowser](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser#readme). However, it does require [Grapelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli), which is an extension of the default admin interface—if that's a dealbreaker for you, you might try one of the forks that attempt to remove Grapelli, like [django-filebrowser-no-grappelli](https://github.com/wardi/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli).